# WP-Snap too slow (caused by WP_Query?)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query, query-posts, query

I have a website with 10.000 posts... WP Snap alphabetizes the posts and puts it out with WP_Query, but it is slow as hell, which is very frustrating. My question would be: what can I do about it?

Is there any alternative to wp_query? Or is the cause of this problem something else?

Comment: WP-Snap hasn't been updated in over 2 years. Consider using another plugin which is still maintained

Comment: I know that. Thanks guys... But what different approach? WP Snap gives me everything... Other plugins don't output a horizontal list with links to the posts. That's very annoying.

Comment: If you need all 10k posts, I would expect that sorting 10k posts is going to be slow no matter what. [`WP-Snap`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-snap/trunk/wp-snap.php), even if not broken, does a lot of work and appears to replace the main query with one of its own concoction. That may be more than you need. If you want a good answer, the better approach in my opinion is to provide details about what you _require_, rather than ask (implicitly) how to fix an outdated plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer to this question is: **don't use this plugin, because it is outdated**. I couldn't write a better code, so I am going to use alternatives like `A to Z listing` and `WP-Glossary`. I hope the developer of this great plugin will update the code, because it is a very useful plugin if it could contain more than 1000 posts...

Thanks for your comments.